# Prove the subset is closed

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that a subset P of C(the set of all complex numbers) is closed if and only if C\P is open.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. I understand that if P is closed then it contains it's boundary. This means C\P is open because P contains it's boundary so the boundary or limit points in P have been taken out (along with the rest of P) of C from C\P.

Comment: Your definitions of *closed* and *open* sets would be …?

Comment: My definition of closed is that $C$ is closed whenever $C \setminus P$ is open.

Comment: Closed sets are sets that contain all of their boundary points.

Comment: Where an open set contains no boundary points, making all of the points in the set an interior points.

Answer (score 1):

Very intuitively speaking, if $\mathbb{C}\backslash P$ is open, then it does not contain its boundary. So, you are "removing *something* with a boundary from $\mathbb{C}$". But since you are removing $P$ from $\mathbb{C}$, $P$ must have a boundary, and therefore it is closed.

Note that to formally show this, you must specify what topology $T$ of $\mathbb{C}$ you are using - then, if $\mathbb{C}\backslash P\in T$, then be the definition of a closed set as the complement of an open set, $\mathbb{C}\backslash\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash P\right)=P$ must be closed.